# big O algorithm -sorting

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

I am learning big O algorithms and I learned all of them but now I can't remember the name for one of them. 
Let's say I have a deck of cards and I am trying to sort them by throwing them on the floor and hoping they get in order. What is that algorithm called? the one that jumbles the numbers in a list again and again until they are sorted.
I know this is like the worst big O scenario but do not remember the name for it.

please help me

thank you

Comment: [bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort)

Comment: And just so you know, "big O" is a notation for measuring algorithm's complexity. **Any** algorithm's. You can't possibly have learned all the known algorithms, can you :)

Comment: I hope you aren't arguing that this one is good :) lol

Comment: Don't even try to learn all algorithms, it's way better if you learn where to find the relevant information. There are simply way too many algorithms and some are even just made out of fun/stupidity or simply to never be feasible at all (for example bogobogosort which is absolutely absurd).

Answer (score 4):

This algorithm is called [Bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) .

Answer (score -1):

Bogosort - the name from bogus sort cause it's pretty bad when it comes to worst case big O(infinity).